# How to send data for base64Binary when calling asmx webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I have to call a asmx webservice, which accepts AttachmentData as a parameter. This has a member with type of base64Binary.

```
<s:complexType name="AttachmentData">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FileName" type="s:string" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UploadedUserName" type="s:string" /> 
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Attachment" type="s:base64Binary" /> 
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

I am sending the contents of a file for Attachment member as follows:

```
//read the file contents
byte[] buffer = null;
     try {
        FileInfo attachment = new FileInfo(filepath);
        using (FileStream stream = attachment.OpenRead()) {
           if (stream.Length > 0) {
              buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
              stream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length);
           }
        }
     }
     catch {
        buffer = null;
     }

//create AttachmentData object
WebSrvc.AttachmentData att = new WebSrvc.AttachmentData();
att.FileName = fileName;
att.Attachment = buffer;
```

Is this the right way to send base64Binary? Do I need to encode the file contents to base64 or is it done on the fly? I am trying to see If I am unnecessarily bloating the size of the webservice request by using above code.

Comment: are you having problems with this code?

Comment: No, it is working fine but I am just thinking about the size of the request. Just checking to see if there is a better way to do the same with less size on the request. Also, I am trying to understand how byte array is converted to base64Binary and what is the difference between byte array and base64Binary the size wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Base 64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) requires 4 bytes in the output for every 3 bytes in the input so there is a bit of overhead but it's not that much.

The nice thing about Base 64 encoding is that it only uses printable characters so it's easy to embed in the HTTP protocol which was built to work with human readable text characters.

In your code example the byte[] buffer is automatically converted to Base 64 before being placed on the wire (i.e. embedded and transmitted in the HTTP protocol).